# Iterating over lists in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
   "month": ["January", "February", "March"],
   "volume": [1,2,3],
   "target": [6,8,5]
}
```

I'd like to loop over each key and value so that I can make a list that looks like this:

```
["month: January, volume: 1, target: 6", "month: February, volume: 2, target: 8", "month: March, volume: 3, target: 5"]
```

How do I loop through each key value one by one until I reach the end of the last list's array value? All lists are the same length for each key.

Comment: Looks like a job for zip https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip Along with simply iterating. Have you tried? Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

```py
d = {
   "month": ["January", "February", "March"],
   "volume": [1,2,3],
   "target": [6,8,5]
}

keys = tuple(d)  # ('month', 'volume', 'target')
values = tuple(zip(*d.values()))  # (('January', 1, 6), ('February', 2, 8), ('March', 3, 5))

your_list = [
    ', '.join(
        f'{keys[i]}: {value[i]}' 
        for i in range(len(keys))  # range(3) in this case
    ) 
    for value in values
]

print(your_list)
```

Output:

```py
['month: January, volume: 1, target: 6',
 'month: February, volume: 2, target: 8',
 'month: March, volume: 3, target: 5']
```

Comment: `keys = tuple(d)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all values have same length:

```
di = {
    "month": ["January", "February", "March"],
    "volume": [1,2,3],
    "target": [6,8,5],
}
sample_length = len(list(di.values())[0])
final_list = []
for j in range(sample_length):
    list_item = []
    for key, val in di.items():
        list_item.append('{}: {}'.format(key, val[j]))
    final_list.append(', '.join(list_item))
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
['month: January, volume: 1, target: 6', 'month: February, volume: 2, target: 8', 'month: March, volume: 3, target: 5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example:

```
di = {
   "month": ["January", "February", "March"],
   "volume": [1,2,3],
   "target": [6,8,5],
}
```

One idea is just to convert it to a list

```
li = [ [k + ": " +str(v) for v in v_list] for k,v_list in test_dict.items()]
```

and then do the join using zip

```
[ ', '.join(l) for l in zip(*li) ]
```

This is the result:

```
['month: January, volume: 1, target: 6',
 'month: February, volume: 2, target: 8',
 'month: March, volume: 3, target: 5']
```